# Updating the view outside of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you update the view outside of the React render method does the virtual DOM update? I'm loading a few base templates async and then just updating components with react, I'm just worried if I change out a template am I working against the performance increase of the virtual DOM diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to update the DOM outside of Reacts control, and it's a common way to integrate plugins that doesn't use React into a React component. But you really shouldn't use both React and some other template system to render the same DOM node.

What you should do is just return an empty `<div>` in your `render` method, and get a hold of that DOM node in `componentDidMount` to render something into that node with your other template system.

Something like:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    var node = React.findDOMNode(this);
    otherTemplateSystem.render(node, {some: data});
  },
  render() {
    return <div></div>;
  }
});
```